# After upgrading React app to vite, node-fetch cause error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, vite

bit stumped of this one. Switching the build tool over to vite has been super smooth bar this error

No matching export in "node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs" for import "RequestInit"
No matching export in "node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs" for import "Body"

a dependancy is causing this issue, but unfortunately is a privately maintained package that I can really do much with.

Package.json

```
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.1.4",
    "@ThePackage/CausingIssue": "^2.3.28", <------------------------------------ error
    "antd": "^4.19.5",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "msw": "^1.2.2",
    "prompts": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-query": "^3.38.0",
    "react-refresh": "^0.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "socket.io-mock": "^1.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.52",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.44",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.15",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "less": "^4.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
  }
```

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        math: "always",
        relativeUrls: true,
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  }
})
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "declaration": true,

    /* Custom*/
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

What have I done so far?

- lots of google, searching stackoverflow
- mixing and matching @types versions
- chatGPT
- dove into the packaage confim node-fetch is there and the erroring exports are infect there
- suspect a typescript / type issue

Comment: Can you try the following changes in tsconfig.json
```target: "ESNext",
moduleResolution: "Node",```

Comment: @CodeBird thanks for the suggestion, it didn't work unfortunately but I did dive the problem libraries dependencies and found that node-fetch in that package doesn't export the Body or RequestInit methods. I guess the vite/rollup build tool is reporting this error instead or ignoring like webpack did. Would be good to just ignore the error if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, posting incase it helps anyone else

adding the following below works, it tells the build tool which dependency to use when there are multiple. In this case

the main application is ESM so by defult it tried to load the ESM version of node-fetch. reolsving to the CJS version fixed that error. Worth noting that node has a native fetch implementation now, so if I'd had access to the failing package probably would have been best to refactor.

Secondly (not in the question but worth a mention), Stream, Buffer didn't have prototypes in node so resolving to stream-browserify created a fill that resolved a .prototype undefined error.

this goes in the vite.config.js/ts

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "node-fetch" : "node-fetch/lib/index.js",
      "stream" : "stream-browserify"
    },
  },
```